# Outlook 2013 Disable notifications from another users mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

User A has User B's mailbox in their outlook.

Since adding it, User A now gets all of the notifications from User B's calender.

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

No way. Sorry. The only thing you can do is to disable all reminders in Outlook Advanced options.

Comment: Apparently with the previous exchange version this never happened.